# Aumentar limite de tamanho de upload de arquivo no user.ini

Tags: php

O usuário está tentando fazer upload no site que eu cuido. Porém, aparece mensagem dizendo que o arquivo é muito grande. Queria poder alterar isso via PHP. Mas, teria que ser no **user.ini**.

Como fazer isso?
Tentei usar as mesmas diretivas que são usadas no **php.ini**. Não funcionou.

```
upload_max_filesize = 50M
post_max_size = 50M
```

O erro:

> 413 Request Entity Too Large

Comment: Comigo funciona normal eu crio um arquivo chamado **.user.ini** com `memory_limit = 50M    upload_max_filesize = 50M     post_max_size = 50M`

Comment: @usuario eu fiz isso, mas o erro persiste.

Comment: o seu arquivo está nomeado com um "ponto" **.** no começo? **.user.ini**

Comment: Não está não. Deveria estar?

Comment: Sim. o padrão e com um **.** no começo

Comment: Tentei com o . no começo e o erro persiste.

Comment: Vamos [continuar esta discussão no chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/62088/discussion-between-usuario-and-felipe-stoker).